# Timed out when access SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm developing a web project and for a start I need to create tables, procedures, views, etc.

At the first (and in debug mode) the code is running fine and the first tables are created but suddenly the transaction throws me an error `Timed out`

If I start again to run the code (in debug mode) it doesn't make any change

In order to run and continue to create the rest's I have to `build` the code again (without have made any change on it). I `Published` again and then continues to create more until will stops again and make the same actions as before.

I haven't test it yet in my web to see what will happen, and the reason is simple... my ISP didn't giving me the choice to create one more data base (because that is my contract I use).

Any way I need to know why that happens?

I have to say that I use some delays in my code especially when it reads from an xml file this file contains structure's of tables, procedures etc. And from where I read and execute thru my code behind in vb.net.

Comment: It will be impossible to help you without seeing any code, where the problem occur.

Comment: There is no any specific piece of my code to show you, because that happens in various times without having the opportunity to catch it. Also some times says that the vs10 is `Busy and for that reason I have to inform Microsoft` but I really can't do that because I don't believe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts finding solution, I noticed that the problem starts from the reading of the XML File, I set in this file some `sleeps` of totally 300 milliseconds and the code now runs ok but slowly...
Thanks to all for there assistance